# How do I set a Window/Application icon in a application set up with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I think I am missing something obvious.  But since the main window of my Application is a UserControl that is being launched by

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>();
}
```

in my bootstrapper how do I set the Icon of the window itself and of the application in the toolbar?

Comment: Don't know anything about the Caliburn. I'm wondering is it able to setup the application icon from the properties of the project, which is the normal way? And you'll want to run the application without debugging to see the icon, otherwise(when debugging) it'll show the icon of the yourApp.vshost.exe (actually no icon).

Answer (score 8):

- **XAML based solution**: Change your `MainWindowView` base class from `UserControl` to `Window` (both in .xaml and in .xaml.cs), then set your `Icon` property or any other window-specific properties right in xaml.
- **Code based solution**: `DisplayRootViewFor<T>` takes an optional settings parameter:

  ```
  var settings = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
      { "Icon", new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication2;component/icon.png")) },
      { "ResizeMode", ResizeMode.NoResize }
  };

  DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>(settings);
  ```

  The keys should correspond to the window properties you want to set, and the value types have to match.

Answer (score 1):

//default settings for windowmanager.createwindow

```
public interface IPropertyKeyValue
{
    string Key { get; }
    object Value { get; }
}
public class PropertyKeyValue : IPropertyKeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class PropertyKeyValue<TValue> : IPropertyKeyValue
{
     object IPropertyKeyValue.Value { get { return this.Value; } }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
public class IconProperty : PropertyKeyValue<ImageSource>
{

}
 public class WindowManager : Caliburn.Micro.WindowManager
{
    public List<IPropertyKeyValue> DefaultSettings { get { return _defaultSettings; } }
    private readonly List<IPropertyKeyValue> _defaultSettings = new List<IPropertyKeyValue>();

     private void Populate(ref IDictionary<string, object> settings)
    {
        if (DefaultSettings != null && DefaultSettings.Count > 0)
        {
            if (settings == null)
                settings = new Dictionary<String, object>();

            foreach (var prop in DefaultSettings)
            {
                settings[prop.Key] = prop.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    protected override System.Windows.Window CreateWindow(object rootModel, bool isDialog, object context, IDictionary<string, object> settings)
    {
        Populate(ref settings);            
        return base.CreateWindow(rootModel, isDialog, context, settings);
    }
}

//bootstrapper
protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
{
    if (service == typeof(IWindowManager))
        return this.Application.FindResource("wm");
    return base.GetInstance(service, key);
}


/*
 <local:WindowManager x:Key="wm">
                    <local:WindowManager.DefaultSettings>
                        <local:IconProperty Key="Icon" Value="favicon.ico"/>
                    </local:WindowManager.DefaultSettings>
                </local:WindowManager>
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of what I do. I just put it in the window definition.

```
<Window x:Class="YourApp.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BudgetPlannerMainWPF.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Icon="C:\...Path...\YourIcon.png"
        Title="Your Title" Height="500" Width="910" FontSize="14"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" Topmost="True" SizeToContent="Width">
```